# Looping and indexing over large arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, processing-efficiency

I am trying to find the indicies in a python numpy array that is 700x700 in order to find the number with the same indices in a separate array. I am looping over this a large number of times so it is taking really long and I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this. So far this is what I have:

My `lat_end` and `lon_end` are the indices that I am finding in the `temp_mask` array.

The mask is creating a footprint over my 700x700 array with a ring size that is defining how large I want the footprint to be. The `mask_index` is finding where the `temp_mask` equals 1, so I can find the indicies for the separate array by doing something like:   `other_array[footprint_index]`. This will then give me the values of other_array that are in the footprint of the `temp_mask`.

```
def foot_mask(lat_end,lon_end):
    mask = footprint.footprint(ring_size,ring_size,700,700, 0)
    temp_mask = np.roll(np.roll(mask,lat_end,axis = 0),lon_end, axis = 1)
    mask_index = np.where(temp_mask == 1)
    return mask_index
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the `mask` is the same for each iteration, I guess the key is to take as many calculations as possible outside of the loop. Besides that, the code looks reasonably efficient.. as long as `footprint.footprint` isn't the dominant time consumer.

Comment: How would I put a for loop inside of the function so that it returns the mask_index for each time it iterates over the loop? I would have it iterate 7 times through the loop in order to change the 'ring size'

Comment: Are you also changing (for instance) `lat_end` or `lon_end` in another loop? Because 7 iterations isn't all that much for this piece of code. Could you maybe edit the question to include how you -intend to- call this function? If you haven't implemented any of the loops yet then pseudo-code or plain English would also help.

Comment: I am iterating over this loop about 150,000 times. There will be around 4000 lat_end and lon_end points that correspond to different latitude and longitude points in my data. Then for each of those points, I am iterating over it about 7 more times for different time stamps that I am using.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail the problem you are trying to solve? Ideally, post your own slow-but-working code and show how to generate some fake input data so that we can see what the inputs and desired output are. I suspect that there may be vectorized approaches that are much faster than calling `foot_mask` inside a loop, but I don't have nearly enough information to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you would like to call this function for many iterations and it already makes use of efficient Numpy functions, I think the key is to move as much code as possible outside of any loop(s) there may be. This does mean that the current function `foot_mask` can't be used as-is but should be refactored a little.

It's not entirely clear to me how you intend to call your function in a loop, but basically I'm suggesting to code something like this:

```
for ring_size in ring_sizes:
    mask = footprint.footprint(ring_size,ring_size,700,700, 0)
    I, J = np.where(mask == 1)

    for lat_end, lon_end in data:  # Or some other loop(s)
        mask_index = ((I + lat_end) % 700, (J + lon_end) % 700)
        # Then use `mask_index` as desired
```

This way there would be less calls to `footprint.footprint` and `numpy.where` and the code should run faster. Also the calls to `numpy.roll` have been replaced by taking the modulus of the indices.

How to organize the loops exactly and how big the speedup would be is hard to say without more information though.

Comment: This worked beautifully! I went from having my code run in 45 minutes to 5! Thank you very much, this will save months of processing!

Comment: When I do this, it seems to order it in the mask_index array. Is there a way to not have it ordered?

Comment: @Kate - I need some more context here ;). Do you mean a random order or..? Maybe you could edit your question to include more details, like the overal goal, the outer loops and the code for `footprint.footprint`. And the significance of the order of the result.